# No valid ext_emconf.php file found for package in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I want to install an extension via direct upload in Extension Manager. But allways i get the Message "No valid ext_emconf.php file found for package ...". Somebody out there that can help with this problem?

```
<?php

$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array (
    'title' => 'Interfrog Themeconfiguration',
    'description' => 'contains all themeconfiguration tables config,color,font,colorshemes without an existing theme',
    'category' => 'misc',
    'author' => 'Interfrog',
    'author_email' => 'info@interfrog.de',
    'author_company' => 'Interfrog Produktion GmbH',
    'state' => 'beta',
    'uploadfolder' => true,
    'createDirs' => NULL,
    'clearCacheOnLoad' => true,
    'version' => '2.3.1',
    'constraints' => array(
        'depends' => array(
            'extbase' => '7.6',
            'fluid' => '7.6',
            'typo3' => '7.6',
        ),
        'conflicts' => array(
        ),
        'suggests' => array(
        ),
    ),
    'autoload' => array(
        'psr-4' => array('Interfrog\\IfThemeconfiguration\\' => 'Classes')
    ),
);

?>
```

Comment: File content looks good, tested. File permission checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At our last Usergroup we figured out the reason. We found out that the problem arises when zipping the extension locally on Mac OSX command line. All files looses its access rights and properties that causes the effect that the ext_emconf.php can't be found during the install process. If you download the zip from an installed live system everything is fine.

We doesn't work out the correct command on Mac OSX command line. It would be awesome if someone can work out the right command for zipping on command line.

Answer (score 4):

Dependencies **must have** both upper and lower boundaries defined.

Technically your line `'extbase' => '7.6',` has no value at all.

- Do you want to restrict from 7.6 upwards?
- Or restrict to a maximum of 7.6?

What's 7.6 after all?

- 7.6.9970970?
- 7.6.0?

You see, there is no valuable information that can be pulled from this.

This is why you need to provide specific boundaries like this for example:

`'extbase' => '7.6.15-7.6.99'`

### PSA:

Be **extremely** careful with loose upper bounds. We see people going `7.6.0-9.99.99`.
Unless you own some magic crystal ball that can foretell the future, it's better to raise the dependency constraints once you actually tested them.

Comment: Thanks Mathias for answering, we solved the problem in the last usergroup, that wasn't a dependency problem. I will add a answer to show the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the issue on a Mac**

The problem is not (only) the hidden MAC_OS folders. The issue is, that OS X does not put the content of chosen Typo3-Extension-Folder into the archive but the folder as single root element itself. Then Typo3 cannot find the files. You must go into the extension folder and run then the zip command.

Example: We are in my working directory which is named *output*. The extension folder is called *jfmulticontent_3.0.0-dev_201810051125*. Then you would have to run:

```
BOB-NB2:output bob$ cd jfmulticontent_3.0.0-dev_201810051125/
BOB-NB2:jfmulticontent_3.0.0-dev_201810051125 bob$ zip -r -X ../jfmulticontent_3.0.0-dev_201810051125.zip *
```

Comment: PS: A Windows VM with WinRar helped me to find that out. :D